# Map dispatch function to properties with react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

How can you access dispatch functions passed to a component via the react-redux connect method? If I try to access the callback via this.props. the function is not found. The following errors are displayed: *Required prop `onDataUpdated` was not specified in `EditTable`* and *TypeError: this.props.onDataUpdated is not a function*

`ConsumerIDManagement.js`

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
var React = require('react');
var EditTable = require("../components/EditTable");

const ConsumerIDEditTable = connect(
  mapDispatchToProps
)(EditTable)

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    onDataUpdated: (oldRow,newRow) => {
      dispatch({ oldRow: oldRow, newRow: newRow,type: "onRowUpdated"})
    }
  }
}

<ConsumerIDEditTable data={this.state.data} editableColumns={["consumerID"]}/>
```

`EditTable.js`

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDataGrid = require('react-data-grid');
var ResultFormatter = require("../components/ResultFormatter");

var EditTable = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        onDataUpdated: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
    },
    ...
    handleRowUpdated : function(e){
        var rows = this.state.rows;

        // inform dispatcher of changed data
        this.props.onDataUpdated(rows, e.updated);
    },
    ...
    },

    render:function(){
        return (
            <ReactDataGrid
                ...
                onRowUpdated={this.handleRowUpdated} />
        )       
    }

});


module.exports = EditTable;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`connect` method has the following signature:
`connect([mapStateToProps], [mapDispatchToProps], [mergeProps], [options])`

1. `[mapStateToProps(state, [ownProps]): stateProps] (Function)`
2. `[mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, [ownProps]): dispatchProps] (Object or Function)`

You need to pass your `mapDispatchToProps` function as a **second** argument

```
const ConsumerIDEditTable = connect(
  null, mapDispatchToProps
)(EditTable)
```

More info in the [docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)

You also declare `mapDispatchToProps` with `const` after you use it. It is `undefined` when you call `connect` method. `const` and `let` are not hoisted up to the top of the document, it means that you can not define them after you use them.

```js
const value1 = 'value1';
console.log(value1, value2)
const value2 = 'value2';
```

Comment: Passing it as the second argument does not help
const ConsumerIDEditTable = connect(
  null, mapDispatchToProps
)(EditTable)

Comment: You also declare `mapDispatchToProps` with `const` after you use it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to watch a video on how to write `connect` functions by Dan Abramov himself [Redux: Generating Containers with connect()](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-generating-containers-with-connect-from-react-redux-visibletodolist). He does a very good job describing on how to create connect functions and how to structure your `Redux` application in a more reasonable and proper way.
This 5 minute video should point you to mistakes you made and explain how `connect` function works.